# How to show lambda is an element in the set {2,3}

Tags: mathjax

I'm trying to ask a question on our friendly neighboring site, math.stackexchange.com and I'm new to mathjax and couldn't get what I need from this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference so I have come here for help.

I'm trying to show lambda is an element of the set (2,3) but I can't get the curly brackets/braces to be it. I can write it using parentheses, but not brackets (it makes a difference).

currently, I have $\lambda \in (2,3)$ but what I need are for those parentheses to be curly braces, and I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

MathJax is largely a subset of LaTeX, so when in doubt, refer to TeX documentation.

In this case, you need to know that curly braces are a common delimiter in TeX, and so they have to be escaped if you literally mean curly braces.

So, what you need is `$\lambda \in \{ 2,3 \}$`. Make sense?